# How to pass the data from ViewModel to Activity in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

### *What I am trying to do: pass the data from ViewModel to Activity*

**ViewModel.cs**

```
    public event EventHandler RecommendedScents;
    private void _recommendedScents()
    {
        var handler = RecommendedScents;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new System.EventArgs());

    }
```

**Activity.cs**

***I register the Event in view***

```
ViewModel.RecommendedScents -= SetRecommendedScents;
ViewModel.RecommendedScents += SetRecommendedScents;
```

**Get the Control here:**

```
    private void SetRecommendedScents(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use such trick to pass data from ViewModel to View.  Just declare your View as `MvxActivity<MyViewModel>`

And you will have a property ViewModel in your View.

```
[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MyView : MvxActivity<MyViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var myValue = ViewModel.SomeProperty; // here you access your VM
    }
}
```

If you need to send data from ViewModel to View, you need to use a a Event aggregator system like MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger?scroll=1524